# PGBEG is cutting off FILE argument

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am trying to recompile a fortran77 program on my linux mint machine. Everything works except for a PGPLOT disply. I got PGPLOT running by following instructions here: http://www.lorene.obspm.fr/pgplot_quick.txt

Apparently PGPLOT is installed correctly, but it cannot find my "prefered output device" as described in the installation instructions (near the bottom). It looks like PGBEG is cutting off my argument at 3 characters because when I put "/xwin" as the "FILE" argument, I get

```
PGPLOT /xw: Couldn't find program "pgxwin_server" in the directory named
```

but when I pass in "/ps", the program runs without errors and saves the output image as a post script file.

Is there a way to make PGBEG accept all 5 characters of "/xwin"? Or am I missing something else?

UPDATE: I had single quotes around the argument. Changed to double quotes and it ran correctly. According to [Difference between double and single quotation marks in fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997887/difference-between-double-and-single-quotation-marks-in-fortran) there should be no difference, though. Why does it matter here? Is it something pgplot specific?

Comment: What has the linked question about quotations in Fortran source files to do with quotation in Windows terminal prompt? Or where are you putting that command? You actually didn't show any quotations originally. Please describe what *exactly* you are doing?

Comment: near as I can tell the issue lies with a string argument to a function called `PGBEG`.  @fyodrpetrovich you need to give more detail so people can understand what you are talking about.