# Fortran write character " into CHARACTER variable

Tags: fortran, special-characters

I have a Fortran file where at a certain point I have to write a command line into a batch file. This works well:

```
CHARACTER*260 TLINE1
. . .
TLINE1= 'c:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\Origin92_64.exe'
. . .   
WRITE(4,'(1A260)')TLINE1
```

and in my Batch-File I get

```
c:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\Origin92_64.exe
```

Now I want to add another Text. I want to have in my Batch-File this line:

```
start "" c:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\Origin92_64.exe
```

My problem now is that I cannot write the `""`-characters into that line directly. I tried this but it won`t work:

```
CHARACTER*260 TLINE1
. . .   
TLINE1= 'start "" c:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\Origin92_64.exe'
. . .
WRITE(4,'(1A260)')TLINE1
```

**Do I have to wrap these characters somehow?**

edit:

I tried:

```
TLINE1= 'start '"' c:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\Origin92_64.exe'
TLINE1= 'start '""' c:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\Origin92_64.exe'
TLINE1= 'start '"''"' c:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\Origin92_64.exe'
```

but nothing worked. Fortran didn`t compile. Message: error#6054 A character data type is required in this context

I got the solution for my question:

```
  TLINE1= ' c:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\Origin92_64.exe'
  T1A = 'start "" '
  TLINE2 = ' -c %TEMP%\amix'
  TLINEGES =trim(T1A)//trim(TLINE1)//trim(TLINE2)
```

Comment: What do you get as output if it isn't as you'd expect it?

Comment: Please *never* use *"It won't work"* or *"it doesn't work"*. It does not tell us anything useful. Tell us what happened. What was exactly wrong?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997887/difference-between-double-and-single-quotation-marks-in-fortran

Comment: I tried the solution given in the link - still got this error

Comment: @user3443063 what compiler are you using?

Comment: Also, what is your target Fortran standard?

Comment: I use Microsoft Visual F# 2013

Comment: You don't need to try any of those three added (and each is wrong): as the linked answers try to explain, the literal `'"'` is a double quote.  There's no need to nest, or use the "triple" form.  Your `TLINE1= 'start "" c:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\Origin92_64.exe'` should be correct.  Please give the result of that.

Comment: When doing so I get Error #5120 Undetermined character constant, Compilation is aborted

Comment: Can you try with a declaration as `character(len=260)` ?

Comment: I did it with 2 variables that I pasted together. This worked fine:        TLINE1= ' c:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\Origin92_64.exe'
      T1A = 'start "" '
      TLINEGES =trim(T1A)//trim(TLINE1)

Comment: Can you update the question instead with proper formatting and a concise explanation of what you did? (aim, code, error message)

Comment: There is no reason that a plain `TLINE1= 'start "" c:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\Origin92_64.exe'` should not work. You might have a temporary workaround but it is a stretch to call it a solution in the perspective of other readers on SO having a similar problem.