# Fortran compiling error: Unexpected elements

Tags: compilation, fortran

I am compiling a Fortran code using F77 (I tried with gfortran as well); however, I got some compiling errors as below:

Code:

```
c  ** write 'ass.ini' file **

    open(17,file=inifile,status='unknown')

    write(17,1001) ext1

    write(17,1002) ext2

    close(17)

1001    format('\'.',a1,'\'             ext1')

1002    format('\'.',a1,'\'             ext2')
```

Compiling errors:

```
 1001 format('\'.',a1,'\'             ext1')
                 1

Error: Unexpected element ‘.’ in format string at (1)

 1002 format('\'.',a1,'\'             ext2')
                 1

Error: Unexpected element ‘.’ in format string at (1)

  write(17,1001) ext1
                   1

Error: FORMAT label 1001 at (1) not defined

  write(17,1002) ext2
                   1

Error: FORMAT label 1002 at (1) not defined
```

I tried with advance="no" but could not fix. I am new to Fortran, I would like to get some suggestions to fix this error please. Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use an extension where the backslash character is intended to escape the apostrophe character.  Read the gfortran documentation.  There an option named `-fbackslash` that gives what you likely want.

Comment: And if you want a literal (single) quote you have [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30997887/3157076) beyond escaping.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to do that and it seems I can compile the code but the output file is: line 1: \..\             ext1; line 2: \..\             ext2 and what I want is: line 1: '.e'  ext1 and line 2: '.n'  ext2 . Could you please check if I have done the right thing as you suggested: 1001 format('\.',a1,'\             ext1')
1002 format('\.',a1,'\             ext2')

Comment: @steve Thank you Steve. I am looking into that.

Comment: You want `format("'.",a1,"'....")`.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you soooo much!

Comment: Please do not add any `[Solved]` to question titles. We have other options here (see the [tour]).